# What's the difference between Windows.System.Threading.ThreadPool and System.Threading.ThreadPool?

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8

The Windows Phone 8 SDK documentation doesn't describe a difference between `Windows.System.Threading.ThreadPool` and `System.Threading.ThreadPool`.  Is there any difference between the two besides the obvious API difference? For example, do they use the same pool of threads? If there is an underlying difference, which should I use and when?

Comment: I believe they should be the same, try this in the IDE. Type System.Threading.ThreadPool and hover over ThreadPool. If they are the same, you should see a couple things, one of them will say somewhere either "Windows.System.Threading.ThreadPool" or "System.Threading.ThreadPool". If it says "Windows.System.Threading.ThreadPool" then they are the same.

Comment: If you can reference System.Windows.Threading.ThreadPool in your Phone8 project's C# source code then there's something pretty wrong with your project setup.  Have you actually tried it?

Comment: @HansPassant, I can definitely reference Windows.System.Threading.ThreadPool and it does work.

Comment: @StevenT, I didn't see any indication that they are the same or that one is a facade of the other, if that's what you meant.

Comment: @HansPassant both namespaces are available for WP8. Windows.System.Threading.ThreadPool (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.system.threading.threadpool.aspx) and System.Threading.ThreadPool (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.threading.threadpool(v=vs.105).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Windows.System.Threading.ThreadPool is "safe" to use within a XAML based application, System.Threading.ThreadPool is the standard API available to all .net application types.

If you are developing a XAML app for WP8 or the windows app store, use the Windows.System version.

Comment: Thanks very much @joe-caffeine.  What do you mean by "safe"?  Is there a technical reason to use one over the other?